# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET trying to click to another .html file

Tags: html, django, http-status-code-404, django-urls

I've done so much research I must have clearly missed something done or something wrong. The server I'm running is `localhost:8000` It actually happens on all three .html files.
I've added the homepage everything works fine until I try to click on another `html file` and recieved.
[Screenshot of the error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmvK9.jpg) `Page not found (404) Request Method: GET trying to Using the URLconf defined in user.urls,`  Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:`

```
admin/
secret/
home/ [name='home']
home/ [name='contact']
home/ [name='Project']
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
  index/Project.html.
```

Here's the `root urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from portfolio_django import views
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', include('admin_honeypot.urls', namespace='admin_honeypot')),
    url('secret/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', include("portfolio_django.urls")),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

from django.urls import path
from portfolio_django import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('', views.Project, name='Project')


views.py

from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def Portfolio(request):
    return render(request, 'Project.html')


def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

Comment: Can you please include the error messages you are receiving

Comment: The page not found was the error at the start was the message I was reciving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving error 404 because you haven't defined a url pattern for http://localhost:8000

You need to change path`('home/', include("portfolio_django.urls"))` to `path('', include("portfolio_django.urls"))`

and change the following:

```
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('project/', views.Project, name='Project')
```

Comment: I tried that again shortly after I posted this but still no luck with the html files.

Comment: @SeemsToBeStuck are you receiving the same error?

Comment: Yes, expect its just [name='home'] [name='contact'][name=Projects].

Comment: Hi @SeemsToBeStuck I have amended my answer, can you please try it now.